# MySQL - Does checking if INSERT query didn't fail (ie, $sql exists) guarantee that registration data is correct in DB?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, sql-insert

Our company is creating (very active) registration forms. The application that processes this data is a Laravel 5 application. I am trying to eliminate all unnecessary queries in the registration processing script. But note that it is **even more crucial** we record every registration properly.

Right now I wrote this into the application flow:

```
$entry_timestamp = time();

DB::table('form_registration_data')->insert($userDataArray);

$matchArray = array('last_name' => $last_name, 'entry_timestamp' => $entry_timestamp);// the (required field last_name / unix entry_timestamp) pair is (safely IMO) assumed to be a unique "ID"

$sql = DB::table('form_registration_data')->select('entry_id')->where($matchArray)->first();

if (!empty($sql)) {
    //from this point script knows user data was recorded properly
} else {
    $errorMsg = 'There was a problem with the server. Please try again.";
}
```

The reason I wrote a separate select query is I am not **100%** certain that just because the insert query didn't fail this means it executed properly and the data is correctly recorded in the DB (remember, this is the most crucial aspect)

In other words, this is why I didn't write the script like this:

```
$sql = DB::table('form_registration_data')->insert($userDataArray);

if ($sql) {
    //was the data truly recorded properly - 100% guaranteed ???
} else {
    $errorMsg = 'There was a problem with the server. Please try again.";
}
```

Did I take this too far? In other words, does the non-failure of the insert query GUARANTEE that the correct data has been recorded in the DB?

Comment: Why not try fetching it based on `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and see if it's in there to be sure? If it didn't fail it probably succeeded, but there's no guarantee something else didn't delete it or won't delete it in the future. Programming is full of uncertainty.

Comment: Agreed, if you use ORM and assign that variable the values to save.  you can use the $data->id to check for the save.  If id is not there, it didn't save.

Comment: @tadman True - but the question is focused at the point of script execution - not deletions in the future. No other part of this script has any delete functionality

Comment: Unless you have reason to believe it failed, it's safe to presume it succeeded. The only way to know if your confidence is reasonable is lots of testing.

Comment: @arcee - but if the ID is there, is it GUARANTEED that the proper data recorded? The primary key autoincrements, but perhaps the rest of the insert array is empty 1 in 10000 times

Comment: I have a script in place which emails me whenever the form ID is empty (not set by user, it's in the form by default), and it does happen that users submit data and the form ID is absent (maybe once in 2000 entries)

Comment: if you properly assign the values to the variable object, and hit save, the ID value is after the fact, not before.  The ID is grabbed during the transaction.  It's part of ORM.  if there's no ID, it did not save.  If it saved bad data, then you assigned the variable object incorrectly as a whole.

Comment: @tadman....thinking about it more and perhaps a nice method combines your approach, but instead I can write select query using orderBy('entry_id', 'desc')

Answer (score 0):

This will work.  You can also use $data->id to reference JOINED tables as a FOREIGN KEY insertion:

```
// In your models file, this will set table.
class Registration extends Model {

    protected $FIELD1;
    protected $FIELD2;
    protected $FIELD3;
    protected $FIELD4;
    protected $FIELD5;
    protected $FIELD6;
    protected $FIELD7;
}


//In your controller:

$data = new Registration();

$data->FIELD1 = VALUE1;
$data->FIELD2 = VALUE2;
$data->FIELD3 = VALUE3;
$data->FIELD4 = VALUE4;
$data->FIELD5 = VALUE5;
$data->FIELD6 = VALUE6;

if($data->save()) {
    echo 'ID:  ' & $data->id & ' Saved.'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The number of fields can vary greatly per registration form and can be changed by the form's author at any time. Also performance matters and joining huge tables to check foreign keys is not something I want to do. See my last comment for IMO a simpler "middle ground" approach

Comment: ok.  Check this out then: http://laravel.io/forum/04-30-2014-saving-dynamically-created-form-field-array-to-db-laravel-way